# Why is my Xbox One video so choppy?

Tags: xbox-one

I've noticed over the past couple days that any video I play on the Xbox One, be it through Amazon Video, Netflix or HBOGO is very choppy. Almost like it's skipping frames.

I've tried hard resetting my Xbox One but that didn't help. Is anyone else having this issue and does anyone know how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

It's not consistent through the entire video, for example, it's only every other scene in a movie but it's very annoying. I also have a very good and very reliable internet connection.

Comment: Does it skip on other devices? Are there other people using your network at the same time?

Comment: No, doesn't skip on other devices and only I am using the network